# Was the ISS closer to Baja California or California when this ISS press event started? When exactly did it start?

Tags: iss, nasa, low-earth-orbit, public-involvement

The NASA video [Expedition 63 Inflight with New York Times, Fox News, and USA Today - July 7, 2020](https://youtu.be/cguaS3Y6BFE) begins with NASA astronaut and Expedition 63 commander [Christopher Cassidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Cassidy#Expedition_62/63) discussing with an unidentified New York Times reporter:

> **NYTimes:** …I guess I’m curious just how far away you are from us, and if you had to drop a pin and I guess you would never do that but which country would it land in? What are you over?
>
> **Cassidy:** Let me answer that question in about 20 seconds, we’re depending on a computer to open up a program, but we’re orbiting 250 miles above the Earth **and it looks like we are abeam<sup>1</sup> of Baja California, just a little bit out into the Pacific Ocean.**
>
> **NYTimes:** mm-hmm, ***so over America!***
>
> [long pause]
>
> **NYTimes:** I don’t know if you’re… so basically you are above us; the US-Mexican border.
>
> **Cassidy:** Yeah, right, we’re just over the Pacific Ocean. We just passed California heading south<sup>2</sup>.

**Question:** When did this interview begin exactly? What area was the ISS above exactly when this interview began?

**note:** If we can get a date and time stamp we can check the TLEs if necessary to get the location, so what we really need is the time.

---

<sup>1</sup>abeam: *Nautical, Aeronautics.* at right angles to the fore-and-aft line (from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abeam))

<sup>2</sup>It seems things “[went south](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44974/12102)” in more ways than one.

Comment: companion question: [What is the blue and purple glitter dinosaur above NASA astronaut Robert Behnken in this video?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45238/12102)