# What is the blue and purple glitter dinosaur above NASA astronaut Robert Behnken in this video?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object, space-art

The NASA video [Expedition 63 Inflight with New York Times, Fox News, and USA Today - July 7, 2020](https://youtu.be/cguaS3Y6BFE) includes NASA astronaut [Dr. Robert Behnken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Behnken), and above can be seen a blue and purple glitter covered dinosaur (I think).

What is the story behind this dinosaur; how and when did it get there?

[image]

Comment: companion question: [Was the ISS closer to Baja California or California when this ISS press event started? When exactly did it start?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45237/12102)

Comment: It was a lot of fun watching it float in and out of view during the post-thrust phases of the trip to ISS. If you watch carefully, you'll see it shortly after the capsule reached a "weightless" condition

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The dinosaur, an Apatosaurus named "Tremor" is the unofficial third crew member (in the DM2 webcast also sometimes jokingly referred to as a stowaway) of SpX-DM2. It was chosen by Doug Hurley's and Bob Behnken's sons, who are both dinosaur fans.

Plush toys have somewhat of a tradition of being used as a zero-G indicator in spacecraft, since they are small, lightweight, fun, and pose no danger to equipment or crew when floating around.

This is not the first dinosaur on the ISS. In fact, there was even a dinosaur born on the ISS: Karen Nyberg sewed one for her son, who is, of course, also Doug Hurley's son.

Comment: His name is Tremor.

Comment: I read that, but I couldn't remember whether the "dads in space" actually said that. It is the brandname of the toy, so that might be a mistake in that article. I also saw an article that talked about two toys, a dinosaur, and a "Ty flippables plush toy", and I looked it up, and Tremor actually *is* a brand name for a glittery plush dinosaur toy by Ty. So, don't trust what you read on the Internet, I guess :-D

Comment: Is knowing that you're in zero G really something that is difficult to determine and a frequent thing you ask yourself when in flight?

Comment: @Muuski: That depends on whether you are in the capsule or not. Remember that SpaceX Crew Dragon Demo-1 won two Emmy awards, so it is safe to assume that there were more people outside of the capsule than inside looking at the toy.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I just saw and heard Bob and Doug repeatedly referring to him by the name "Tremor".

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad to see that `species-identification`questions are now officially on-topic in Space SE! Somewhat related: [How did the largest/longest dinosaurs hold their head and necks up?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/64666/27918); apatosauruses (apatosauri?) are sauropods :-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm always here for you with the critical technical details :)