# Gravitational field of the Moon and Earth

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, physics, gravity, lagrangian-points

Is there any method to find a point or plane in space where the gravitational field of the Moon and Earth are the same?

And if so, what happens to a spacecraft if it passes through that point or crosses the plane (in engine shut-off condition with zero acceleration)?

Comment: I would imagine all Lunar spacecraft have passed that point.

Comment: You may enjoy https://what-if.xkcd.com/157/

Comment: My man rediscovers Lagrange points

Comment: @OrganicMarble They didn't pass through it. The trajectories from Earth to lunar orbit and from lunar orbit to the Earth passed well away from that point, but not because bad things happen. The goal was to get to the Moon. That point is rather useless, but it is harmless.

Comment: @Topcode The point the OP was asking for is not one of the Lagrange points. See PM2Ring's answer.

Comment: @DavidHammen out of my wheelhouse again.

Comment: This question and the answers is a great illustration of the dangers of reading more into something than what is actually there. Often when a statement or question is purposefully silent on certain aspects humans have a tendency to 'fill in the blanks' using their experience base even when the blanks are not supposed to be filled in with anything.

Comment: I would have sworn the term for this is "gravitopause", but Google disagrees with me.  The responses referring to this point as Lagrange Points are incorrect, those are solutions to 3-body stable orbits.  The points are probably close to L1 and L2, but it's a mistake to actually call them that.

Comment: @Greg Miller I propose using the term Zero G-Spot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the gravitational field is a field, there's a couple ways this question could be interpreted:

1. The magnitude of the gravitational accelerations due to the Earth and Moon are equal
2. The gravitational accelerations due to the Earth and Moon are equal in magnitude and direction (they contribute the same amount of acceleration)
3. The gravitational accelerations due to the Earth and Moon are equal in magnitude and opposing in direction (they cancel out)

I'm going to point out that each of these interpretations gives a different answer. I'm going to assume you meant the last one.

This point in space is called EML-1, or the Earth-Moon Lagrange point 1. Here's an image I stole from Wikipedia/Wikimedia that shows where you can find it.

[image]

If you were to coast an object through this point, it would accelerate very little, as the gravitational accelerations of the Earth and Moon cancel out. It would still accelerate a little bit due to the gravities of the Sun, Jupiter, and literally everything else in the observable universe.

This and the other Lagrange points are locations where apparent accelerations due to gravity from the Earth, gravity from the Moon, and the rotation of the whole Earth-Moon system due to the moon orbiting cancel out. If you were able to go to one of these and stop moving (relative to the rotating Earth-Moon system) you would stay put. Well, you'd stay put for a while--eventually those little accelerations from the Sun, Jupiter, etc. (even the lumpiness of mountains on the moon) would perturb your stable orbit & you'd drift off. This is worse at EML-1, -2, and -3; EML-4 and -5 are more stable.

Worth noting: all/most two-body gravitational systems have a set of associated Lagrange points, including the Earth-Sun system. Sometimes, we [send things to them](https://webb.nasa.gov/content/about/orbit.html).

Comment: Due to the eccentricities of the orbits, the distances to the Earth-Moon Lagrange points vary a little. Here's a weekly plot for EML-1 for last year, using data from JPL Horizons. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xswb4.png

Comment: have you worked out the simple math to prove gravity force is indeed equal and opposite?  My understanding of Lagrange points is that they relate to angular velocity matching... not gravity force equaled.

Comment: the question pertained to gravity force alone, not centrifugal force balancing against gravity.

Comment: Fair point, @BradV. OTOH, EML-1 *is* the point where an object "floats" between the Earth & Moon. And we kind of have to work in a rotating frame for that to happen.

Comment: yes @Pm 2Ring... in a sense that is true...but was not the question. Stand-alone gravity forces exist without motion or momentum. The EML1 point just happens to coexist on the same line between Earth and Moon.

Comment: @BradV Sure, but if the Earth & Moon start at rest with respect to each other, they won't stay that way for long. They'll crash!

Comment: The Lagrange points are calculated from the perspective of a rotating frame and therefore include the fictitious centrifugal acceleration. I don't think this is what the OP was after. However, the Lagrange points are much, much more useful than the useless point in space that the OP asked for.

Comment: This question and answer are about the Earth-Moon Lagrange points (assuming the question OP was imprecise in what they were asking), but the image you've included primarily shows the the Lagrange points for the Sun - (Earth-Moon) system. While it would be possible to use that image in order to give the reader a *feel* for where Lagrange points tend to be in a two-body system, it would be beneficial if you explicitly explained that the image isn't showing the Earth - Moon Lagrange points. As it currently is, the image is confusing.

Comment: It would also be beneficial to be more precise in stating that the Lagrange points are where the combined gravitational fields of the bodies balance out to the centripetal force necessary for a sustained, (mostly) stable orbit at those points (volumes). You stating you're assuming the OP means "The gravitational accelerations due to the Earth and Moon are equal in magnitude and opposing in direction (they cancel out)" is not what you actually discuss. The Lagrange points are very likely what the OP *intended*, but correcting the OP and being more precise in answering is helpful.

Answer (score 8):

The point you seek is near the Earth-Moon [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point) L1 point, but not identical to it. I'll call your point the centre of gravity; note that it is *not* equal to the [centre of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass). In this answer, I'll calculate the location of the centre of gravity and compare it to the location of the L1 point.

I'll use the same notation as Wikipedia's Lagrange point article. $M_1$ is the mass of the Earth, $M_2$ is the mass of the Moon, $R$ is the distance between them, and $r$ is the distance from the point of interest to the Moon. (All distances are measured centre to centre).

From Newton's law of universal gravitation, at the centre of gravity (CoG) we have
$$\frac{GM_1}{(R-r)^2} = \frac{GM_2}{r^2}$$

Rearranging,
$$\left(\frac{r/R}{1-r/R}\right)^2 = \frac{M_2}{M_1}$$

It's convenient here to work with ratios.
Let
$q = M_2/M_1$,
$x = r/R$,
$s = 1 - x$.
In other words, we're working in units where the Earth-Moon distance is $1$, the distance from the CoG to the Moon is $x$, and the distance from the CoG to the Earth is $s$.

So
$$\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)^2 = q$$
which leads to
$$x = \frac{\sqrt q}{1+\sqrt q}$$
and
$$s = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt q}$$

Note that when $M_1=M_2$, $q=1$ and $x=s=\frac12$. Also note that these equations are symmetrical: if we swap $x$ & $s$, we get the inverse mass ratio, $1/q$.

For the Earth & Moon, $q \approx 0.0123000369$. That gives
$x=0.099833$
$s=0.900166$
Using $R=384975$ km for the mean Earth-Moon distance,
$x=38433$ km
$s=346541$ km
Please see my answer [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49269/16685) for plots of the annual variation in the Earth-Moon and L1 distance.

---

Wikipedia gives this equation for the L1 point:
$$\frac{M_1}{(R-r)^2} - \frac{M_2}{r^2} = \left(\frac{M_1R}{M_1}-r\right)\frac{M_1+M_2}{R^3}$$

That simplifies to
$$\frac1{s^2} - \frac{q}{x^2} = s - qx$$
Hence
$$q = \frac{s-1/s^2}{x-1/x^2}$$

That leads to a 5th degree equation in $x$, which can't be solved algebraically (in general), although it's easy enough to solve numerically. However, we don't need to solve it to compare it to the centre of gravity.

We get
$$q = \left(\frac xs\right)^2 \left(\frac{1-s^3}{1-x^3}\right)$$

Note that the factor on the left is the equation for $q$ for the centre of gravity. The factor on the right is [close to $2x$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLIae.png) for small $x$, so it's fairly close to $1$ when $x$ is close to $0.5$.

Here's a plot comparing the L1 and centre of gravity distance.
[image: Plot of L1 & Centre of Gravity vs mass ratio]
Here's a live version of [the plotting script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtVN9vmzAQfvdfcWLaYqcuI9kyRZV46rRuUrugtVIfojZywBBvBEfGSaHT_vedDaHrFB7guPu--20HQQBJqS1ci8KIqpBwPQFRZZDKyhoJOgfUH5Rt4VDDVtQ1GGGVJgTwuTfKWlnBuoXkBqY_VFXANJpOw2gWTj-RIAgIyY3eItHuMEqp1qFV6S9pQG132li4TUUpzBdtEGGl-R99hJk0EUZsa0KOUrjfZcJK-hsTGTXOabgVP7UJa_UsRxfwkQ9qVb2oI-7w7Wl8exL_hxFSlKqSNcSwRHqmUktTXWoTj97M5_MRh2dtMmniiPHTdk-3bSnj0Xn_-6Qyu4mjcDawJ8h-ICST2HMPpqXmsFEcait3-N6vncAufO9LjenkpdYGYfDeYxiM_dcDNgoBqVQlRemEPZOlFQhxCmfvvHtTrnFAoCrwK0EncNY5cp7OMTJDvKezPhn3tEqWmUvrDLnjzs6h69xSwdtjBIhjiPo6RZatCqMymnBwza-HKuves58hBz8aTNaDOgMCUY9vV0NP8hYj7d5U3RiG7Dwx7mIMShfa5xe_AL2-a38SNrgMlHFwkmic1OfjojN-mtQOpLYntX0Rr0mMdG9yEIaOmhEjbsMm2OGG5CjRxo2FPU5J4UaNPaXOWD9-cP33coMyIQma3YGhyxwb_sCBRhxwszByKQtZZatSrGUZL4PLxVXAIbieBA-OF95-XdyvFsndt8X32-OJssriniIG3sHlcAtcdbcAskUj684hti34rGorqlQGPLgZboeAvYKt3GGKJ-Fk5orPVeH_5xxyPMkyvjN7yWE8_ncZaIR3iCsCDwVQlGaMYcb1Rj_RhP0F0g5jnQ==&lang=sage).

Here are daily distance plots, courtesy of Horizons.

[image: Distances from Earth]

[image: Distances from Moon]

---

Here's a quick hack of my Lagrange potential surface script, originally from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57679/38535). This version also calculates the CoG distance, and plots it as a green dot at the same height as L1.

[Interactive 3D Lagrange surface plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFVt1u2zYUvtdTHKgXoVJZsuS47QIr2BCsvXG3oOuwAoFr0BJlc9OfKSqxXfQ59kB7sZ1DSraTdVuAWOLhOd_55Ue5rgt3Ra2Bw5yvFa_WAppaVrrFhxaVlryAtlM5T4UD-PebkhrlsNrD3XuIP8hqDfE4joNxFESRUfm1ybgWWS-eBvEreJR6A7f1O8d1XUeWTa00lFw36LmQq6DZNyYGdFpo54Er5u78vX9wPcfJRA6VeNQs96Hzro0HRIG3sspA1WhW55B3VaplXQHpcgUd6rYU2k9oWVcXLZRCb-qMLA1ClkMCmVDygWv5IAh855mdvFYgQVZgisG-610aox0a5WyXdB6ECGHejrsdjBByd1y_gEZhIZn0wb12fYop253UZQ581TIUwQwiMYria1gpwf8wGkroTlXQOU67qR_ZRpcFu7i4cGabq5uzRj3r0CzEbWfW3HzcyHYQAiG0oDfnBlknQNeAQA9Sc1M6jvVMcVvJvFujChYCjbEQZKlq0sKCKpELJSqchlzxUlDxOejHGlZ1tod232pRklEjVC5SDalUaVdgS8qavATOLGxuMELnI6KijRQtcIU41s8n4DvZ-nZgSFDy37EhBpxrGJsojVxWZ_IoAMJ7PsII7JRc_YHDiPPalrzAUjUbTKC1Bp8grWuVyQoHtqVcCPr25_fATCVMeiVvW89H6btzqa3cHjcoonnkwzzu3ycmIdN8kT1NeCbKGxvbLMRXaDgVUQuFcSByXdg-bTteIPgQkCz5WgTw49rvE0umY0h5QYWluElnOKN27Kfjv_60_5B2K8zWROHMOGywgYm70bppr8Pw7AzWah22mq8KEWL3C6H2YVoXtbK_JW-Wx9YHNI4vBvnoKHdvnNteCD3GLOQ3Dg6uhyf5eyqI4qk2Z3rJtglzqbh40nA08IRE4RvPx_Hvk5yMfTi0mKdARfM0OhOjk6KT5BdR4IzViiFtBEM8LcOmoAfeFTpxFZfVqn5Ey4KvRJG4Rg2b2rgGZ4UtaxHfitN9WogWla-sExImbtOphpyjJKuXfXTMfTZtaPVRdcKimsFO3vKiFbQ2Z6VfAu90vewMSVpRTzGUEhIM5bIWeklLRj9Yup4wtnAD0YmPtqgdIRNtrcILM9J41taiPxlIAng42NgfY0nMlJSmLUYaodTYbSPE2cJLiHqY2yezTygs9aHXTo0yOrXaluNcPDPEcRVLPe8fKP1ZCbB56nNM9iGLRsr7HFuu69NgEcbQbpVm2x7kCP7OgivPO0_1RGcD_1sGxwXD-8NDXLaDEaToCaH35jcmT5jypXW1G7Y8jzYvt0-3jX3knZQG_x94JjtDGXSAempcDyEonqHzeFBeUw0PQtVU-IEr5hOzu6aLSOY5M2Hvk3Gf-5a6iykLXiwrvVnSVccouokPk1McPzSNqnfIEJrYrKlbSXUwgT1zNKfb6z7CfLZbPEeYED1H9FKx7eXrMIq9xVBdHOQT2Jm5uYnXdBObi7Ijqp_vFqeb07cyUXUlnnUt2HyHzs4uUdvT3IX5F_n1Gr50X11vmO_j6Tqpz3sqR98Mb1CkhJHtb4IrU62ngfQJvOe7fvrnV1iBqREjNb4aI5Lp7MQL7fgdNhJlA2oUxoRrVL2gYja2Q1GTzlXw2iIdaGbJcERb_x9-IHY4qhm7ZwbfoPsEgOfSikZnskXfXaJJpCBmvoXOStjRYB-sb_oSwWguLZEdVYbvB1TKC7ziWPcvJ-f82-4OcfHjrJCp1Esa60mGbpJjcbAwFG86wvH2IX2JD1rbZb_AkPrE-lgshzJ8-IbhUImgBxq1j0GZtw0S-tJcCAkyVOTbCwCNLIWaXx8epHg0lsn9_dgfjYOpPw7eTBc4apPp4kmqloqHFtnVqZR38DKx_D2h7iBT-lRU39CjeUVMm4L5pd4dRBJPjz6e3QL_MQtPfPWD8S3waOp924YpcwB60_vx4j5eeAOCu1ZCVO4Zhp15-ny88_4GxYh-4Q==&lang=sage).

Comment: I'm going to be a bit 'rough around the edges' here so I can get right to the point. After all is said and done (lots more math/ratios/graph) was my 'quick and dirty' answer right or wrong? Is the Anton Hengst answer (accepted as correct) really correct?

Comment: @BradV I believe that the OP is asking about the centre of gravity, not the Lagrange point, so your answer is more correct than Anton's. But at that small mass ratio, L1 & CoG are very close.

Comment: regardless of how close the numbers are... Anton guessed,  guessed wrongly, and provided 'answer' that sounded good but misled others.

Comment: @BradV Anton wrote a great answer... to a slightly different question. I don't agree that it's misleading, exactly, since he does mention that the Lagrange points include the centrifugal force as well as the two gravitational forces.

Comment: I regret I was harsh. This reminds me of a test question in "Design of Machine Elements" course. Question specifics were carefully tailored so if you chose solution path A you got answer 12.345. if you chose solution path B you got answer 12.567. Both answers would pass the smell test (felt right enough) but path A was not really applicable. The point was... details matter.  I used this example when mentoring junior engineers and designers. Getting a close enough answer for the wrong reasons can lead to catastrophe.

Comment: @BradV Understood. In this business, accidentally calculating the wrong thing can end up costing billions of dollars &/or killing people. Fortunately, I don't think anyone's at risk due to the answers on this page. ;)

Comment: ABSOLUTELY TRUE !!!  this balance point is trivial. Critical thought is NOT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136612/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-bradv).

Comment: Near the L1 point the gravitational fields of the Earth and Moon are about the same magnitude but in opposite directions.  The chart of the Lagrange points also considers the centrifugal force of a rotating coordinate system.

Comment: @RossMillikan Indeed! I have more details on that on the answer linked in the last section of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I approached my solution by placing a mass of XX between Earth and Moon. Radius from Earth to Moon is $3.84 \cdot 10^{8}\ m$. ($D_e$) Distance from Earth to mass is R - ($D_m$) distance from Moon to mass.

Gravity force on mass from Earth:

$$\frac{G \cdot M_e \cdot XX}{D_e^{2}}$$

Gravity force on mass from the Moon:

$$\frac{G \cdot M_m \cdot XX}{D_m^{2}}$$

after setting the two against each other, cancelling terms $G$ and $XX$, and solving for distance, I come up with a "equal gravity point" at  $3.46 \cdot 10^{8}\ m$ from Earth... 90% of distance to Moon.  Please check my work!!!

How close is my calculation to EML1 location?

EDIT BradV 5/26/2022  add graphic

distances and diameters are to scale

[image]

Comment: If you use gravity acceleration instead of gravity force you don't need a mass XX.

Comment: 346,000 km is around the maximum distance from the centre of the Earth to  EML-1. See the graph I linked in my 1st comment on Anton's answer.

Comment: @PM 2Ring my calculation and your distance to L1 sure seem to align well!

Comment: If the formatting I applied is wrong, then my apologies. I did my best but could have messed something up. For example, I now see that `Distance from Earth to mass is R - ($D_m$) distance from Moon to mass.` probably should have been `Distance from Earth to mass is $R - (D_m)$ distance from Moon to mass.` Cheers.

Comment: @PM 2Ring  it would be interesting to pursue 2 aspects further. 1: are the locations of EML1 point and EM 'equal gravity force' point identical or just happen to be close together. 2: would same hold true for other solar system combinations like Sun-Earth, various other mass ratios.

Comment: @BradV They're always fairly close, but they're only identical if the mass ratio is 1. I guess I can post an answer that compares the two...

Comment: @PM 2Ring in our side chat you used the term COG (Center of Gravity, better known as CG) and on your COG, L1 plot within your answer regarding the location where earth and moon gravity sum to zero.  Since CG is already a defined and widely used engineering term that has a very different meaning, I'd like to propose another term.... the "Zero G-spot" ;-)  rimshot/cymbal crash.

Answer (score 2):

The gravitational field is a vector quantity.  Near L1 we can find a point where the gravitational fields of the Earth and Moon are equal in magnitude but they will be opposite in direction.  To have them the same magnitude and direction you want a point on the Earth-Moon line but beyond the moon.  To find this point we recall that the gravitational field from a body of mass $M$ at a distance $R$ is $\frac {GM}{R^2}$ toward the body.  If we let $M$ be the mass of the Earth, $m$ be the mass of the moon, $r$ be the distance to the Moon and $R$ the distance to the Earth, we are asking that $$\frac {GM}{R^2}=\frac {Gm}{r^2}$$.  We will use $380\,000\ \mathrm{km}$ as a reasonable distance from the Earth to the moon, so this becomes
$$\frac {GM}{(r+380\,000\ \mathrm{km})^2}=\frac {Gm}{r^2}\\
\frac Mm=\frac 1{0.0123}=\frac {(r+380\,000\ \mathrm{km})^2}{r^2}$$
and we find $$r=47\,000\ \mathrm{km}$$
so the point is $47\,000\ \mathrm{km}$ beyond the Moon.  Nothing special happens if a spacecraft passes through this point.  The gravitational field is what it is and the acceleration is what it is.

Comment: This is an interesting take on the question!! Super!   This is a very interesting matter of semantics and interpretation of what the question really asks!  So... Gravity force due to Earth is A. Gravity force due to Moon is also A. SO total gravity force acting on mass is 2A in your interpretation.

Comment: About a spacecraft passing thru the point... correct, nothing special happens. Trajectory would increasingly bend towards Earth/Moon as approaching point and ease as leaving.

Comment: @BradV:  yes, I read the question as asking for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there would be a point where gravitational fields of moon and earth would be same.
When the spacecraft passes through this point net Acceleration due to net force because of field being zero.
The spacecraft would cross that point because acceleration would be zero means it would be moving with some constant speed at that point.