# What is the distance between Mars and the lagrange point L2 Mars Sun?

Tags: mars, orbit, lagrangian-points, geostationary, geosynchronous

I am writing a science fiction novel that is more soft that hard sci fi but I would like to know at least an estimat of the distances between L2 Mars Sun and Mars. I know that asking for an exact number would be stupid due to the elliptical orbit of Mars but I would like an estimated number in kilometers.

Comment: Using my 3D diagram script here, https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57679/38535 I get L2 at 1.00476343 & L1 at 0.99525165. That's the distance from the Sun, in Martian astronomical units, so multiply those numbers by the mean distance from the Sun to Mars. Of course, the actual distances will vary a bit due to the eccentricity of Mars's orbit. Some people will say we shouldn't even be talking about Lagrange points of non-circular orbits... ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm one of those people sometimes but I also apparently wrote an answer to [How far would the Mars L1 Lagrangian Point be from Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25991/12102)